# lodash refactor filter function

Tags: typescript, refactoring, lodash

I have the following code, both components use a lodash filter, how do I abstract the function so I dont repeat the code?

```
<VictoryScatter
          style={{
            data: { fill: BRAND_COLORS.white, stroke: BRAND_COLORS.chartLine.gradientGrayStart, strokeWidth: 3 },
          }}
          size={5}
          data={_.filter(loanLimitData, (value, key) => {
            return key !== 0 && key !== 6;
          })}
        />
        <VictoryScatter
          style={{
            data: { fill: BRAND_COLORS.white, stroke: BRAND_COLORS.chartLine.gradientBlueStart, strokeWidth: 3 },
          }}
          size={5}
          data={_.filter(loanBalanceData, (value, key) => {
            return key !== 0 && key !== 6;
          })}
        />
```

So, I need to write a function for

```
_.filter(myArray, (value, key) => {
            return key !== 0 && key !== 6;
          })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the array as an argument:

```
const myFilter = <T extends any>(array: T[]): T[] =>
    _.filter(array, (_, key) => {
        return key !== 0 && key !== 6;
    })
```

FYI you can do the same with the built-in `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
const myFilter = <T extends any>(array: T[]): T[] =>
    array.filter((_, key) => {
        return key !== 0 && key !== 6;
    })
```

In the components you would write:

```
data={myFilter(loanLimitData)}
```

```
data={myFilter(loanBalanceData)}
```